# Can I replace an IC in PCB with another IC with partially different part number?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have the following IC in below picture which is an ECU power driver chip, and its damaged.

[image]

I only found this replacement chip in below picture, but it has a partially different part number, however, it has same function.

Unfortunately, the datasheets aren't available for either of them.

[image]

My question is : can I replace the second one with the first?

Comment: The obvious answer is no if the system uses some function or feature that is present in the original and not in the replacement. You would need to review the datasheets in relation to the circuit schematic to determine that. It may also be subject to control by software elsewhere in the system.

Comment: EE answer: Compare datasheets (if available) or see if the vendor has a compatibility chart for their products. Streetwise answer: Ask in a forum of auto-mechanics. This seems to be the same part with different manufacturing dates and batch numbers but the vendor is not under any obligation to provide the same set of features in revised chips.

Comment: This is supposedly some proprietary(?) part by Bosch but datasheets are nowhere to be found, possibly it was discontinued. You can be dead certain that copy cat crap & silicon dummies are available. So don't buy this from some random scammer you found on the internet. Step 1 is to track down the original datasheet from somewhere.

Comment: It might just be a crappy photo, but the replacement part looks like a potential fake (with all the consequences that might have). The presumed original part has these glossy black bottoms of the two circular dents while the second image shows dents with the same matte texture as the rest of the package. That is a typical sign of blacktopping.

Comment: @Lundin Can you copy cat an IC though? Isn't making ICs is expensive and needs special factories? And don't you need to reverse engineering the IC first?

Comment: Well it depends on if they're the same part (or close enough) or not. Without datasheet you can just guess. You can try it and see if it goes bang and if it does go bang then you wasted both parts and the circuit board.

Comment: @JohnSall Yes to all. Though if you throw quality out the window, it becomes far less complex. Or you can just make silicon dummies then pack them in tape & reel with a few original parts near the opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They ought to be the same parts, widely available. Get extra ones as they are low cost.

[image] [image] [[image: ]3][image][image][image][image]

[image]

Last built circa 2010 when they went to  a smaller package in 2011

Buyer beware of Distributor return policy.

I won't cite sources from these *schlockers.*

They may need to be dried in oven in case of high humidity repackaging and with ESD handling.

Comment: I agree - probably the same part. The other numbers on the part are likely date codes, lot numbers, foundry codes.

Comment: natch.......... they certainly are

Comment: I didn't fine one single serious vendor selling them, just scammers. Nor did I find the datasheet anywhere.

Comment: @Lundin there is one selling them on ebay with $20

Comment: @JohnSall If you are only buying 1 piece then the shipping cost will be most of it, scam or no scam.